# I have installed Firefox 50.0.2 but it is not available through the Dash

Tags: updates, firefox

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. After downloading `firefox-50.0.2.tar.bz2`, I have unpacked it and then installed. When I click on Firefox on the Dash it opens the old version. The new version works through downloaded folder. How to get rid of the old version?

Other question: New Firefox is in the `/Downloads` folder. To which folder should I copy it, to keep it with other programs?

//Edit:

I have just uninstalled old version :)

Then I have used `whereis firefox` command and popped out: `/etc/firefox /usr/lib/firefox`. So I followed these instructions and I found folder with previous Firefox. It still contained a few files. I tried to cut and paste Firefox folder from my `/Downloads` folder but It is not working. How should I copy those new Firefox files so that it will appear in the Dash?

---

Thank you for all your replies. For sure I will study now more about terminal and commands. I tried to avoid it on the beginning before studying it well, because last time I have just erased my other OS by using terminal...

Before I checked this forum I made a small thing. I had accessed  `/etc`folder as an administrator (*right click>access as a administrator*) and then I have just paste new Firefox folder replacing old one. Can it stay there or should I move it to `/opt/` or `/usr/local/` ?

//Edit

I had copied `Firefox folder` to `/opt/` and later I opened the terminal. There I run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall firefox`. Firefox 50.0.2 is working good now and I can run it through the Dash. Reinstallation fixed also Firefox's launchpad icon that was missing before.

Comment: Where you trying to install the developer edition of firefox ?

Comment: I think you're in an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832). To update Firefox, see instructions here: [how to update an individual app through terminal](http://askubuntu.com/a/656550/301745), but at this point you may actually need to reinstall it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't install **applications** into the **download folder**. You can place them in your home or `/opt` folders. So that download should have been in either of these.

Now for what you were trying to do, I am not too sure, but it's a bad idea when you're new to Linux or Ubuntu in particular to install applications from outside the **normal package system**. But in any case we are all learning so to help you I suggest you look at this excellent [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/548003/how-do-i-install-the-firefox-developer-edition), that should be helpful.

If you were trying to do a simple **upgrade** then simply running `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` should help.

Hope it helps, but do visit that question. It's really helpful.

Comment: @wjandrea, excellent edit. Hope I will be that good soon. Thank you

Comment: Thanks @George. Your [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/548003/how-do-i-install-the-firefox-developer-edition) to another topic on this forum  is very useful. Actually there is all I needed to know about installation of new verisions of Firefox.

Comment: so i guess you can mark my answer as the accepted solution ? Glad to have been of help

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you just stick to normal packaged versions of Firefox, and don't install from independently downloaded tarballs.

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal
- Run `sudo apt-get update` (updates the package list on your machine)
- Run `sudo apt-get upgrade` (fetches and installs new versions of your software)

I checked and I can see that Firefox 50.0.2 should be available using the above approach on 14.04 ([source](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/firefox)).

If you want a nice graphical interface for installing software, try `sudo apt-get install synaptic`, then you will have a program called Synaptic that will be accessible from the Ubuntu menu, allowing easy installation of the latest-available versions of a wide range of packages.

Comment: Thanks! I am starting to get more familiar with the terminal. Yours instructions are very clear.